# Postfix sending emails via multiple broadband lines

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, reverse-dns, ptr-record

I have a site that send out emails from a postfix server. They have multiple broadband lines for load balancing and failover. I want them to be able to send out emails though both lines without the risk of being blocked as spam.

Both lines have a static address and have a PTR record on them which also have a records that resolve to the IP addresses

server.domain.com
server2.domain.com

in the main.cf myhostname = server.domain.com

SPF records are also being configured as well

my main question is: should the first line on server.domain.com go down would there be a risk of the emails being blocked as spam if they go though server2.domain.com? as myhostname is different?

Thank you

Comment: Personally, I would arrange for both IP addresses to resolve to server.domain.com. Then you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, would not

**IF**

- server.domain.com (used in EHLO `myhostname`) always resolve to *some IP*
- Paranoid-IP-check for server2's IP can be performed (server-IP-> hostname + hostname -> hostname-IP and server-IP == hostname-IP)

you have correctly configured SMTP-server from DNS-part

Read SMTP-lelated RFCs - it's useful reading for postmaster

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is good to know I am configuring the DNS side of our mail servers correctly